# Google Sign In fails with DEVELOPER_ERROR on Android, fine on iOS

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo, google-signin

I'm using the react-native-google-signin library for my expo project with firebase. I am able to login via google on iOS perfectly but no matter what I try I get developer error on Android. Here are the steps I followed so far to make sure it's not an SHA-1 fingerprint mismatch:

1. My app is in production so I configured the oauth screen and I copied the sha-1 fingerprint from app signing/google play console and added it to my firebase project
2. Ran cd android && ./gradlew signingReport and I added the debug sha-1 to firebase as well (debug and release fingerprints were the same)
3. Those fingerprints didn’t work, so I got the sha-1 of my keystone file as well and added it to firebase. Didn’t work. I currently have all 3 of these fingerprints added to my firebase project.
4. Made firebase configuration to app-level build.gradle as:  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.3') implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics')
5. And in root lvl build.gradle I added classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1') to dependencies
6. I also have this inside my root-level build.gradle configured for the debug key  signingConfigs {
      debug {
          storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
   storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
   keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
   keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
   }
   }

I am still getting developer error so I also tried using the upload key from google play console, but the error persists.
My package name is correct, google-services.json file is correct and redownloaded each time I made a change, and I am using web client ID to initialize google, not android id.

I followed the developer error section from the react-native-google-signin library docs to the T (https://react-native-google-signin.github.io/docs/troubleshooting) and I am absolutely sure that I’ve added the correct fingerprints. No idea what to do from this point. Please send help

Answer (score 0):

Same. Works when i build and run locally on simulator/emulator on both Android and iOS, but when i publish app to closed beta / test flight and run on my own real devices, Android shows DEVELOPER_ERROR, code: 10. iOS on the other hand works as butter